# How to resolve 'ethereumjs-testrpc@beta' error while using 'npm –g install ethereumjs-testrpc@beta' in Nodejs command prompt

Tags: nodejs, npm

While setting up my Solidity Environment Using NodeJS, Node Package Manager (NPM) and Truffle which was successfully installed. But at the point of running "npm –g install ethereumjs-testrpc@beta" I was getting error

I was running everything for the first time on Windows 10 operating system with the latest NodeJS installed. I have tried to check online for various similar error code and how it was solved and still not working

```
C:\Users\****>npm -g install ethereumjs-testrpc@beta
```

I expected to get successful result but got this error code

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ethereumjs-testrpc@beta
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Comment: I am guessing that you need it for `solidity-coverage`, in which case you may as well install its latest version (0.5.11), which automatically downloads `testrpc-sc` along with it.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration. I was actually trying to run npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc with 'beta' which has longtime deprecated. But without the "beta" works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "beta" version of `ethereumjs-testrpc`, as can be seen on the [package's npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc) under "Versions". You could install the package in it's latest version.

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

But testrpc has been deprecated in favour of `ganache-cli`, which works in the same way. If you want to use the most up to date tooling, you should instead install the latest version of `ganache-cli`.

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. I made use of "npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc" without the "beta" and it worked, it seems I was using outdate tutorial online to self-taught myself. Thanks.